# cannot edit any value in this datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

i have a datagridview bould on a list from Mongodb. however i cannot edit the grid. I dunno why its like that?

```
var connstr = "Server=localhost:27017";
mongo = new Mongo(connstr);
mongo.Connect();

IMongoDatabase TorontoTrader = mongo["TorontoTrader"];
IMongoCollection TradingStrategyCollection = TorontoTrader["TradingStrategyRefresher"];
IEnumerable<Document> docs =
   from doc in TradingStrategyCollection.Linq()
   where (int)doc["TriggerBarId"] == 102
   select doc;

dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = docs.First().ToList();
```

Comment: First guess would be that ToList is not returning a collection that has an IEditable interface which is required for gridview editing

Comment: I am not sure becuase under the debugger, the readonly attribute is set to false. http://screencast.com/t/dC63vfoT4

Comment: My understanding is that your collection must support the IEditable interface for a datagrid to support built in in row editing.

Comment: is there any example that you can point to. I am not sure what is the next step i should take. Becoz, the  docs.First().ToList() is a MongoDB C# driver implementation that i have no control on immediately. In the interim, how can i make it work.

Comment: From what I have seen about MongoDB it does not return a Datatable or DataReader or any of the mainstream data objects.  It looks like you would have to add your own controls and catch change events to do in row editing.

Comment: Ouch that doesn't sounds like fun!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must set the ItemsSource of your datagridview to an observableCollection instance.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new ObservableCollection<Document>(docs.First());
```

This probably will make the grid editable, but it will not save back the edits to the database.